# Robot framework: Stop running service by RF which hasn´t been started by RF

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to stop service which is already running so the name of the service is unknown. I know PID of the service but RF process library cannot use PID.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using opertaingsystem library.

Replace "yourPIDhere" with your pid to kill that process

```
Library           OperatingSystem

Kill_Process
     ${rc}=    Run And Return Rc And Output    taskkill /pid yourPIDhere
     Log To Console     ${rc}
```